# 404 для удаленного вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, удаление-вопросов

При попытке доступа к удаленному вопросу (пока ещё не хватает репутации) выводится текст с несколько странным выделением полужирным:

[image: полужирный]

Зачем это выделение? Ссылка и так выделена другим цветом. Почему при этом выделена не только ссылочная часть?

В transifex можно [видеть](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265822?qt=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B), что в оригинале была выделена только ссылочная часть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставить выделение полужирным, но только для ссылочной части сообщения.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю убрать выделение полужирным вообще. Ссылка и так будет видна.